# Yii2 - Extend a controller into an exist module

Tags: yii2

I want to extend a controller from the backend / controller into a my existed module.
The structure of directory in My Yii2 Application as follows.

``

- backend

  - controllers

    - JobOrderController
  - view

    - job-order
- modules

  - marketing

    - controllers

      - JobOrderController [extend from @backend \ controllers \ JobOrderController]

``

When I access the route: localhost / marketing / job-order, I get an error message:

``
View not Found - yii \ base \ ViewNotFoundException
The view file does not exist:
../../advanced/backend/modules/marketing/views/job-order/index.php

``

I don't want to change any view from the marketing module, is it possible?

Comment: What about setting [`$viewPath`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#$viewPath-detail) in the module's `JobOrderController` to `@backend/view/job-orders`?

Comment: But if your goal is to have external controller to appear as part of `marketing` module, setting it in module's [`$controllerMap`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#$controllerMap-detail) property might be better idea, because that way you don't need to add any extra files into the module's structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use controllerMap in Module config.
Also set the view folder.

```
public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        
        // custom initialization code goes here
        $this->controllerMap = [
            'job-order' => [
                'class' => 'backend\components\controllers\JobOrderController',
                'viewPath' => Yii::getAlias('@backend') . '/components/views/job-order'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note. You can set the module's `$controllerMap` property in your config where you are adding the module. You don't need to override the module class to set it in `init()`.